# My Java method won't compile

Tags: java, compiler-construction

I have a problem with my Java method. It doesn't seems to be compiling correct, and I can't figure out what is wrong.

I hope someone can help me check this method for errors, so I don't get an compiling error.

```
/**
 * Calculate the speed in Kilometers per hour.
 * @param lentgh The length drove in kilometers.
 * @param time The time used in minutes.
 * @return The speed in the datatype integer.
 */
public static int getSpeed(double length, double time)
{
    return (length/(time/60));
}
```

Comment: What is the error message? Do  you have this method in a class?

Comment: Especially when the compiler spells it out for you "possible loss of precision found: double. Required: int"

Comment: Sry I am new to the programming in Java, but the error was something with type mismatch and I tried with the (int) in front of my return, and it worked :)

Answer (score 7):

You have to cast the result to `int`:

```
return (int)(length/(time/60));
```

If you want to round instead, use `Math.round`:

```
return (int) Math.round(length/(time/60));
```

Note that you should check whether the speed actually fits in the size of an integer (the case doesn't raise an exception).

Comment: You got 4 points for that!? ;-)